# Extjs 4.x Grid drag and drop records with parent-child relation

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop

I have created a Extjs (4.X) grid which has records of parents and childrens. The records are in sorted order where in the childrens always appear just below their parents as shown here, where 'P' designates a record as parent while 'C' designates a record as children.

'May' is the parent of Peter,  Odin is the parent of Thor and Loki, Bruce has no children yet marked as Parent (standalone entity)

[image]

I wish to change sort order of only the parents while also bringing their childrens along when I drag and drop records within the grid. I have progressed upto a point where I am able to allow only a parent to be able to drag while disallowing a children to be moved moved around. For example if I hold the record 'May Parker', it should be allowed to drop after record Loki, the last child of a parent OR a row before another parent OR after the last row in the grid. I have created a fiddle which works for below cases:

1> Allow movement of only a parent record.

2> Disallow a parent to move if the record that was traversed was a Child. (nodeOver record is a child).

3> Allow a parent to drop if the node over is a child but it is the last row.

The <3> doesnt work right because the nodeOver index gives me last index of the grid regardless of whether I place the Parent either after last row or before the last row.

I have used an override as below:

```
    Ext.override(Ext.view.DropZone, {
    onNodeOver: function(nodeData, source, e, data) {
        if (data && data.records && data.records[0]) {
            // The check should be better specified, e.g. a
            // female with the name 'Malena' would be recognized as male!
            //debugger;
            
            console.log(this.view.getStore().data.items[nodeData.rowIndex].data);
            console.log(data.records[0].data.type);
           // debugger;
            console.log(nodeData.rowIndex +" Hello  "+this.view.getStore().data.length);
            if (data.records[0].data.type.localeCompare('P') != 0  || ( 
                    this.view.getStore().data.items[nodeData.rowIndex].data.type.localeCompare('  C') == 0  &&
                        nodeData.rowIndex != (this.view.getStore().data.length -1 ) ) ) {
                    return this.dropNotAllowed;
            }
            
            
        }
        return this.callOverridden([nodeData, source, e, data]);
    },
    onContainerOver: function(source, e, data) {
        return this.dropNotAllowed;
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle of my progress so far:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ji3

Much appreciated if someone can point me in the right direction for below items

1> How do I club parent and its childrens so that drag and drop clubs and moves all of them?

3> How do I ensure that parents cannot be dropped between another parent and its childrens ?

Please ignore the Ranking provided for the child records,  in real world scenario I intend to provide ranking only for the parent records and for childrens it will be empty.

Comment: Did you think about using grouping?
That way it would be grouped by family name or alike. Then you could drag and drop the grouper.

Comment: Hi @Dinkheller: I created another fiddle with grouping feature but the drag and drop doesnt seem to work for a grouped objects, I wish to disable drag drop for childrens but allow drag drop for groups but for some reason the events are not triggering, what could be the problem?. Fiddle:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3jjv

Comment: Here is a good starting point for grouping drag&drop: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3127

Answer (score 0):

This is better achieved with a treepanel, like: https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#tree-reorder  Works since Ext 2.0. You can D&D any branch (parent) and all the leaves (children) will travel with it.

Comment: Hi @Arthur, I tried the TreeGrid which seems to be something close to what I want but the drag and drop doesnt seem to work natively, when I move the parent it does move the child and it also retains the original child. It might be a bug on extjs code as well (assumption). Here is the fiddle that I tried:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3jju&view/editor

Comment: Hi @vick_4444, just tried with your fiddle: the issue seems to be that the data misses `id` properties. I.e.:  

`
            "id": "P1",  
            "type": "P",  
            "name": "May Parker",  
            "email": "may@domain.com",  
            "phone": "555-111-1224",  
            "rank": 1,  
            "childCnt": 1,  
            "leaf": false,  
            "children": [ [...]  
`
Add an `id`  to each parent and child and it will work as expected.

Comment: Hi @Arthur:  I modified the store data and now it has the ID column , at first I tried with string and then I tried with integer but that doesnt seem to change the behaviour. Updated fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3jju&view/editor

Comment: Hi @vick_4444, the solution is really easy, you can chillout now: use the proper plugin, that is `treeviewdragdrop` and not `gridviewdragdrop`. The behaviour that you are seeing now is that every node is treated like a row; if you use the `treeviewdragdrop` every row will be treated as a node that is a parent or child. Use the option `allowDrop: false` to answer your third question.

Comment: BTW:  `childCnt` is not necessary, you can get the number of children from the node (just get the `length` of the node). Calculating it beforehand can be cumbersome.

Comment: Hi @Arthur: Thank you very much, the allowDrop false for child records and treeviewdragdrop solved most of the problems : ). I still see some issues I have updated the fiddle where if you drag 1st Parent and drop it after 2nd parent right above 3rd parent it gets appended as a child to 2nd parent. Also is there a way to figure out list of records that were modified by this drag and drop ? I wish to save the order to DB so need to obtain their new position/rank.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue: I think it is a matter of precision when doing the drop, it must be dropped exactly in between the two nodes. But to play it safe, add the `"allowDrop"` property to the parents as well. 

Regarding the order: it's a whole topic in itself. Your ranking is working fine. I don't think (I might be wrong) that you can escape traversing all the parent nodes, getting their rank and submitting the order to your DB (Notice that the children keep their order inside the structure). It will get more interesting if you get grandparents :-D

Comment: I have removed 1/3 parents, now it would reproducible everytime if you expand both parents first and then drag 1st parent and make it last parent, basically I am trying to drag 1st P right after the last record such that the 1st becomes 2nd and 2nd becomes the 1st. Instead the 1st P gets added as a child to the 2nd P. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3jju&view/editor . Okay thanks I will loop through records and submit the re order details to backend. Yup thankfully I do not have to deal with 2 levels down : )

Comment: The solution would be to drag P2 on top of P1, and for safety, add `"allowDrop": false` in all the parents before defining the children: in this way you prevent the parent to be dropped inside another parent.   To be able to drop P1 below P2 I think you would have to make the root visible (I haven't tried it though).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3jmf) of your grid-group-header.

The main work is to add a listener to `groupmousedown` and update the eventlistener:

```
        grid.mon(grid, {
            scope: me,
            groupmousedown: me.onGroupMouseDown
        });
```

```
    onGroupMouseDown: function(view, item, groupName, e) {
        if (e.pointerType === 'mouse') {
            var groupFeature = view.findFeature('grouping'),
                group = groupFeature.getGroup(groupName),
                selectionModel = view.getSelectionModel();

            selectionModel.select(group.items);

            this.onTriggerGesture(view, group.items, item, null, e);
        }
    }
```